# Passing changing variable value between classes with listeners

Tags: java, events, arraylist, listener, parameter-passing

As you suggest i rewrite my question. Here is my problem. I have got frame, with 2 panels added. In first panel i create a `Generator` object. In class `Generator` i have got list of objects and timer, which is calling function `addItem()` which is adding new object to my list. 2nd panel (created in frame) need to print a list of object included in my array. if these array will change this panel need to be repaited automaticly. If it looks too confusing take a look on fragments of code

CLASS with JFRAME

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    private MapaSwiata mapa;
    private MyPanel myPanel;

    public MainFrame(){
    //....
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);

    mapa = new MapaSwiata();
    myPanel = new MyPanel(); 

    panel.add(mapa,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(menu,BorderLayout.EAST);  
    //...
}
```

CLASS with 1st panel created in JFrame class

```
public class MapaSwiata extends JPanel{

Generator gs;

public MapaSwiata(){
    //...

    gs = new Generator(this);

            //...
}
}
```

CLASS Generator (with a ArrayList which changes need to be observed)

```
public class Generator{

ArrayList<Object> sampleArray;

public Generator(JPanel p){
    this.s = new ArrayList<Samolot>();
       this.p = p;
      generatorTimer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  addItem();
                  p.repaint();
          }
        });
        generatorTimer.start();
   }
    public addItem(){
      //....
    }
 }
```

Last class CLASS MyPanel - panel which need to be repainted when my ArrayList is changed

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
JLabel label1;
public MyPanel(){

    // to do:
            // print a ArrayList<Object> sampleArray here in JLabels
            // if sampleArray has been changed - my panel repaints itself
    }
}
```

So my questions are: 
1. what is a best way to pass the sampleArray from my class `Generator` to this panel to print it
2. where/how/what listeners to put to let him inform my last class about changes in object created in `MapaSwiata`

Answer (score 0):

AWT and Swing use events to handle that. You should have a method in ClassA that allows registering an event listener. Each time the list is modified in the ClassA instance, the registered listeners should be modified.

So the ClassB should register a listener to the ClassA instance, and this listener should update the panel by getting the modified list from the ClassA instance.

Just as you register an ActionListener to a JButton, and this JButton notifies all its listeners each time it's clicked.

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html

Comment: so as i understand u well, after list is modified i need to do smth like that in my ClassA `listener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 1, "update"));` where `listener` is `ActionEvent` type. what is more i need to do `addListener()` function and then create an object ClassA in my ClassB which implements `ActionPerformed`. then use my `addListener()` function on my object to waiting for signal. Am i correct? can u do some scheme for me of that situation?

Comment: No. ClassB must have an `addXxxListener(XxxListener listener)` method. Each time the list is changed inside ClassB, you must iterate through all the listeners and call their method. ClassA must create an instance of XxxListener and call classB.addXxxListener() with this listener. I wouldn't use an ActionListener for that. A ListDataListener or even simply a ChangeListener would be more appropriate. Look at the javadoc of EventListenerList to understand how you can easily register and call listeners inside ClassB.

Comment: reading 1h of examples and still nothing. in my opinion ClassB should be swaped with ClassA in your advices. but probably i dont understand it well. can u write me some example which will suit for my situation? btw i read about observers but idk are they will be suitable for my problem

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mismatched your two classes. You're right. The class holding the list (ClassA) must have an addXxxListener method. And the class which wants to listen to the changes in the list (ClassB) must create a listener and add it to to the ClassA instance.

Comment: now i understand much more. i can do it except 1 thing. im creating an obcject (ClassA) in OTHER class then ClassB. lets call it ClassC. Im creating there object of type ClassA. And now, if this object is changed, i want to pass new value of object to ClassB and repaint panel there. how to solve this problem?

Comment: Make ClassB add a listener on ClassC, and make ClassC fire an event when its ClassA object changes.

Comment: but how to add a listener to my ClassB when im not creating there any object of ClassA or ClassC. In most cases it looks like `ClassA a = new ClassA(); a.addListener(this);` but in this case i cant do that becouse im not creating neither ClassA nor ClassC object in ClassB

Comment: You need a reference to a ClassA instance (or ClassC instance) to be able to read values from it and display them in your panel, as your question says. So, add a listener to this instance. Who creates this instance doesn't matter. Your question starts to be more and more confusing. Why don't you edit your question and paste your actual code there?

Comment: edited. hope someone will post me where and what exacly i need to do. it is hard to do by myself when im doing it first time

Comment: if u can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309896/change-listener-for-variable-in-other-class